# grep command that matches lines with exactly 2 of every character from a group

Tags: regex, grep

I need help figuring out a regular expression with grep (I can only use grep) that will search a file and display lines that include exactly 2 from each character in [a-f0-9].

Valid matches examples:

```
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a
```

Invalid matches examples:

```
c0 b0 f5 60 02 8b 1c a4 41 7c 53 f2 85 20 a0 d1
```

I tried `'(?:[0-9a-f])?^[^\1]*\1[^\1]*\1[^\1]*$'` but it obviously won't work, because you can't negate a backreference like that, even if I correct it I'm not sure this is the right method.

Comment: Do all the lines look like this (16 groups of 2 hex characters), or does the regex also have to filter totally different lines?

Comment: What is the pattern with the invalid matches?

Comment: @mandy8055 The invalid matches have some characters more than twice, and other characters less than twice.  For example there are six zeroes and no nines.

Comment: which version of grep? Which flavour of regex can you use?

Comment: Using `grep -P` another idea: [`^(?!.*?(\S).*\1.*\1)(?:\b ?[a-f\d]{2}){16}$`](https://regex101.com/r/6uoVbq/1) It is very similar to one of [@jhnc's solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77338582/5527985), so I won't post another answer.

Comment: @bobblebubble I think if `\S` becomes `[a-f\d]` it will fail faster. Anchoring and fully lazy should help too `((?!^.*?([a-f\d]).*?\1.*?\1)`. Remember to set C/POSIX locale (eg. `LANG=C`) otherwise `\d` could match more than intended

Comment: @bobblebubble `\b ?` is very nice

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do there's 3 ways a match could fail - 1) input contains less than 2 of one of the chars in [0-9a-f], or 2) input contains a char that is not in [0-9a-f], or 3) input contains more than 2 of one of the chars in [0-9a-f]. Given that, your sample input should contain at least 3 lines that fail rather than just 1 so we have something we can copy/paste to fully test a potential solution with. It's always easier to match input you expect than to not match input you don't expect and with your current example an incorrect script could produce the expected output.

Comment: You have been asked several questions in the comments above  but you have not answered any. That's a sure way to attract downvotes and votes to close. I am particularly interested in your answer to @Benjamin's question, which he asked two days ago. When answering questions in the comments it's generally better to edit your question than to respond with a comment. That will make the question clearer to all readers, not just to those who read all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

You may do this in a straightforward way of

```
^                           start of line (check docs)
(?=(\S\S\s){15}\S\S$)       matches 32 symbols with spaces
(?=[^1]*1[^1]*1[^1]*$)      contains exactly two ones
(?=[^2]*2[^2]*2[^2]*$)      contains exactly two ones
...
(?=[^f]*f[^f]*f[^f]*$)      contains exactly two Fs
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any [POSIX grep](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html):

```
grep -vEf regexlist filetosearch
```

where `regexlist` contains:

```
[^0-9a-f ]
^ *([0-9a-f] *){0,31}$
^ *([0-9a-f] *){33}
(0.*){3}
(1.*){3}
(2.*){3}
(3.*){3}
(4.*){3}
(5.*){3}
(6.*){3}
(7.*){3}
(8.*){3}
(9.*){3}
(a.*){3}
(b.*){3}
(c.*){3}
(d.*){3}
(e.*){3}
(f.*){3}
```

- can only contain hex and space
- must contain no less and no more than 32 hex
- cannot contain three of any hex (otherwise there would be fewer than two of some other)

This is making use of [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws):

> ( A & B & C & ...) == NOT( NOT(A) | NOT(B) | NOT(C) | ...)

We provide an OR list of regex that must fail and then use grep's `-v` to invert, which results in an AND list of regex that must match.

---

If hex must come in pairs, add:

```
^[^ ] +
 [^ ] +
 [^ ]$
[^ ]{3}
```

For exactly one space between each number, and none at start or end of line:

```
 {2}
^ +
 +$
```

---

If your `grep` supports `-P`, it is simpler. For example:

```
grep -P '^(?!^.*?([0-9a-f]).*\1.*\1)(?!^.*?[^0-9a-f ])(?=[^ ]{2}( [^ ]{2}){15}$).*$' filetosearch
```

- `^` ... `.*$` - match entire line
- `(?!^.*?([0-9a-f]).*?\1.*?\1)` - cannot contain three (or more)
- `(?!^.*?[^0-9a-f ])` - only hex and space
- `(?=[^ ]{2}( [^ ]{2}){15}$)` - exactly 16 pairs

or if amount of whitespace is irrelevant, even:

```
grep -P '^(?!^.*?([0-9a-f]).*?\1.*?\1)( *[0-9a-f]){32} *$' filetosearch
```

---

I believe anchored and lazy:

```
^(?!^.*?([0-9a-f]).*?\1.*?\1).*$
```

should be faster to match (ie. fail) than unanchored and/or greedy:

```
^(?!.*?([0-9a-f]).*?\1.*?\1).*$
```

```
^(?!.*([0-9a-f]).*\1.*\1).*$
```

```
^(?!^.*([0-9a-f]).*\1.*\1).*$
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be the simplest way:

`^(?!.*([a-f0-9])(?:.*\1){2,})(?:[a-f0-9]{2}(?: |$)){16}$`

Basically, it asserts that the beginning of the line isn't followed by 3 or more occurrences of the same character, then matches space-delimited pairs of characters.

https://regex101.com/r/zerktu/1

Comment: this fails: eg `echo 00 11 22 | grep -P '^(?!.*([a-f0-9])(?:.*\1){2,})(?:[a-f0-9]{2}(?: |$))+$'` should not match but does

Comment: @jhnc As I understand it, the OP only wants to exclude strings that have 3 or more of the same character, and `00 11 22` does not, so it should be a valid match.

Comment: not according to the title or the first sentence: "**exactly two** of **every** group" / "include **exactly 2** from **each** character in [a-f0-9]". Note `01 23 45` also matches and definitely does not contain two of anything

Comment: They said "exactly 2 of *every character* from a group," not "exactly two of every group."

Comment: True, I elided that accidentally. Still, the comment makes the intent clearer. "no nines" should not match

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you were saying that the string needs to contain everything in the character set exhaustively. In that case, the pattern can be fixed by quantifying the last part with `{16}` instead of `+`, since any fewer and we'll be missing something, and any more will give us 3+ copies of something. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I understand the OP needs a grep solution for some reason but others with a similar problem reading this question in future may not have that same restriction.

Given this input where the first line is valid but the last 3 lines cover what I think are the 3 possible failure cases (**1)** input contains less than 2 of one of the chars in [0-9a-f], or **2)** input contains a char that is not in [0-9a-f], or **3)** input contains more than 2 of one of the chars in [0-9a-f]):

```
$ cat file
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a
   e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a x
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a 3
```

and keeping in mind [this saying](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

here's how I'd really approach this, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { chars="abcdef0123456789"; lgth=length(chars) }
    {
        input = $0
        for (i=1; i<=lgth; i++) {
            char = substr(chars,i,1)
            if ( gsub(char,"",input) != 2 ) {
                next
            }
        }
    }
    input ~ /^ *$/
' file
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a
```

Answer (score 1):

If you *have* to use *only* `grep`...
then I think a pipeline would make it a little easier to read and maintain, though I do not like the fact that this design runs `grep` 18 times...

```
$: cat file
c8 f1 7a d9 f2 a7 a0 5a e9 9f c1 4c 2f e3 f5 3b |aanbestedingsdossier|
56 fc 9f 14 da 80 51 3e 74 9a 73 ed 6b c2 80 2b |aanbetaalt|
ce ba ed a0 a5 27 fd 4c 22 a2 1d a1 87 46 91 b3 |aanbranden|
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a |good example|
c0 b0 f5 60 02 8b 1c a4 41 7c 53 f2 85 20 a0 d1 |bad example|

$: grep -E '([[:alnum:]]).*\1.* \|' file              | # lines with at least 2 occurances
  grep -vE '([[:alnum:]]).*\1.*\1.* \|'               | # minus lines with 3
  grep a | grep b | grep c | grep d | grep e | grep f | # now just assert each required character
  grep 0 | grep 1 | grep 2 | grep 3 | grep 4 | grep 5 | grep 6 | grep 7 | grep 8 | grep 9
56 fc 9f 14 da 80 51 3e 74 9a 73 ed 6b c2 80 2b |aanbetaalt|
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a |good example|
```

Surely you can at least use `sed` to do it all in one pass?

```
$: sed '
  /\([[:alnum:]]\).*\1.* |/!d;              # drop lines without at least 2 occurances
  /\([[:alnum:]]\).*\1.*\1.* |/d;           # drop lines with 3
  /a/!d; /b/!d; /c/!d; /d/!d; /e/!d; /f/!d; # now drop lines that lack any required character
  /0/!d; /1/!d; /2/!d; /3/!d; /4/!d;
  /5/!d; /6/!d; /7/!d; /8/!d; /9/!d;
' file
56 fc 9f 14 da 80 51 3e 74 9a 73 ed 6b c2 80 2b |aanbetaalt|
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a |good example|

$: sed -E '
  /([[:alnum:]]).*\1.* \|/!d;               # drop lines without at least 2 occurances
  /([[:alnum:]]).*\1.*\1.* \|/d;            # drop lines with 3
  /a/!d; /b/!d; /c/!d; /d/!d; /e/!d; /f/!d; # now drop lines that lack any required character
  /0/!d; /1/!d; /2/!d; /3/!d; /4/!d;
  /5/!d; /6/!d; /7/!d; /8/!d; /9/!d;
' file
56 fc 9f 14 da 80 51 3e 74 9a 73 ed 6b c2 80 2b |aanbetaalt|
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a |good example|

$: sed '
  /\([[:alnum:]]\).*\1.* |/!d
  /\([[:alnum:]]\).*\1.*\1.* |/d
  /a/!d
  /b/!d
  /c/!d
  /d/!d
  /e/!d
  /f/!d
  /0/!d
  /1/!d
  /2/!d
  /3/!d
  /4/!d
  /5/!d
  /6/!d
  /7/!d
  /8/!d
  /9/!d
' file
56 fc 9f 14 da 80 51 3e 74 9a 73 ed 6b c2 80 2b |aanbetaalt|
33 e0 f1 76 9c 4f a8 6c 01 5d 45 9e 28 db 7b 2a |good example|
```

You might have to put each of those commands on a line of its own, but this is still better, and probably easier for the next guy to wrap his head around.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Perl one-liner that should do the trick:

```perl
perl -ne 'print if /^[a-f0-9]*$/ && !grep {($_ =~ tr/$_//) != 2} 0..9,"a".."f"' file.txt
```

This command does the following:

- `perl -ne`: Runs the following Perl code for each line in the input.
- `/^[a-f0-9]*$/`: Checks if the line contains only characters in the range `[a-f0-9]`.
- `!grep {($_ =~ tr/$_//) != 2} 0..9,"a".."f"`: For each character in the hexadecimal range `[a-f0-9]`, counts the number of occurrences in the line (`$_ =~ tr/$_//`). If the count is not exactly 2, the character passes the grep filter. The `!` operator inverts the grep result, so the grep expression is true only if all characters have a count of exactly 2.
- `print if`: If the grep expression is true, prints the line.

This command prints all lines in `file.txt` that consist of only hexadecimal characters and where every hexadecimal character appears exactly twice.

Comment: That doesn't match the valid input example for me?

Comment: didn't work for me, also I forgot to mention that I can only use grep

Comment: I apologize I updated the comment

Comment: Produces no output for me.

Comment: `$_` does not interpolate in `tr/$_//`. `perldoc -f y` says: "there is never any variable interpolation, so "$" and "@" are always treated as literals"